# Prove $f(x)=\frac{x+1}{x^2+2x-3}$ is unbounded on the interval $[1,3]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Prove $f(x)=\dfrac{x+1}{x^2+2x-3}$ is unbounded on the interval $[1,3]$

That's basically the question, so I used partial fractions to simplify
$$\frac{x+1}{x^2+2x-3}$$
$$=\frac{x+1}{(x-1)(x+3)}$$
$$=…=\frac{1}{2(x-1)}+\frac{1}{2(x+3)}$$
$$\frac{1}{2(x-1)}+\frac{1}{2(x+3)}\lt M$$
and then I got stuck, do I just get to choose any $M$ for $x$ and then solve it and get a contradiction? Or is there a range of $M$'s that if I go beyond the proof will be wrong? How do I choose an $M$ ?

Comment: Let $M$ be given and then show that $x$ can get close enough to $1$ that the first term on the LHS is too big for the inequality.

Answer (score 5):

First of all $f(x) = \frac{x+1}{x^{2}+2x-3}$ is not defined on the closed interval $[1,3]$, but it is unbounded in the interval $(1,3]$.

Now $f(x) = \frac{1}{2(x-1)} + \frac{1}{2(x+3)} > \frac{1}{2(x-1)}$. Let $M \geq 1$ be any number then we can notice that there exists an element $x_{M} \in (1,3]$ such that $f(x_{M})>M$. Basically if we choose $x_{M} = 1+ \frac{1}{2M}$ will work. So $f$ is unbounded.

Comment: Good first sentence in your post.

Comment: Thanks, @user2661923

Answer (score 3):

$x=\frac{1}{n}+1, n\in\mathbb{Z}, f(x)>\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{10}.$Thus it is unbounded.

Comment: why can you just choose an x?

Comment: @Zivgi NOT one, but a series.

Comment: i dont understand the proof

Comment: @Zivgi There are many $x$ given and you get a set of $f(x)$. The set is unbounded.

Comment: ohhhhh i get it but why is the fact that n/2+1/10 is smaller then x a contradiction

Comment: @Zivgi the issue is not whether $~f(x)~$ is or is not greater than $~x.~$ Instead, the sole issue is whether in the sequence $~\langle a_n\rangle,~$ given by $~a_n = 1 + 1/n,~$ which is entirely contained in the region $~(1,3],~$ does the corresponding sequence $~\langle b_n\rangle,~$ given by $~b_n = f(a_n)~$ grow unbounded?  So, it becomes relevant to ask whether $~f(a_n)~$ is or is not greater than $~n/2,~$ since the sequence $~\langle c_n\rangle~$ given by $~c_n = n/2~$ clearly grows unbounded.

Answer (score 2):

There's actually a very standard proof of this, which I'm surprised no one has mentioned yet: $$f(x)=y=\frac{x+1}{x²+2x-3}$$ Cross multiply now. $$yx²+(2y-1)x-(3y+1)=0$$ Now I'll take it that x must be real, so for all real x, $D\ge0$. $$(2y-1)²+4y(3y+1)\ge0$$ Simplifying a bit :$$16y²+1\ge0$$ which gives the condition $y\epsilon R$.

Answer (score 1):

I like the proof shown in another [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4829887/306553). Its idea is that if it is lower bounded by an unbounded sequence then it is unbounded.  It is very neat.  Here is a slightly less elegant approach.

Note that you do not choose $M$, you assume a challenger give you an $M$ and you show that you can find a higher value of $f$. It has to work for every $M$.

For any $0<\delta<1$, $4<4+\delta < 5$, we have $\frac15 < \frac1{4+\delta}<\frac14$,

$f(1+\delta) = \frac{1}{2\delta}+\frac1{2(4+\delta)}>\frac1{2\delta}+\frac1{10}.$

WLOG, we assume $M>\frac1{10}$, we just have to pick $\delta$ such that $\delta$ satisfies $0<\delta < 1$,

$$\frac1{2\delta}+\frac1{10}>M$$

$$\frac1{2\delta}>M-\frac1{10}$$

$$\delta < \frac1{2\left(M-\frac1{10}\right)}$$

Hence if $\delta < \min \left(1, \frac1{2\left(M-\frac1{10}\right)}\right)$, we can see that $f(1+\delta)>M.$

Answer (score 1):

it is simply unbounded since f(1) is not defined so  values in its neighborhood get arbitrarily big

A more rigorous way to put it is

Assume f has a maximum value in (1,3) at x=M now let $\delta \in (0,M-1)$

$$
f(M-\delta)=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{M-\delta-1}+\frac{1}{M-\delta+3})\gt \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{M-1}+\frac{1}{M-3})=f(M)
$$

This contradicts the assumption that f(M) is the largest value of f in (1,3)

Which means there is no largest value or an upper bound

Comment: thanks ! got it

Answer (score 0):

> Prove $f(x)=\dfrac{x+1}{x^2+2x-3}$ is unbounded on the interval $\,(1,3]\,.$

**Proof:**

For any $\,M\geqslant\dfrac14\,$ there exists $\;x_M=1+\dfrac1{2M}\in\big(1,3\,\big]$
such that
$f(x_M)=\dfrac{x_M+1}{x^2_M+2x_M-3}=\dfrac{2+\frac1{2M}}{1\!+\!\frac1M\!+\!\frac1{4M^2}+2\!+\!\frac1M-3}=$

$\require{cancel}=\dfrac{2+\frac1{2M}}{\frac2M+\frac1{4M^2}}> \dfrac{2+\frac1{4M}}{\frac2M+\frac1{4M^2}}=\dfrac{\color{#0044FF}{\cancel{\color{#000000}{2+\frac1{4M}}}}}{\frac1M\!\color{#0044FF}{\cancel{\color{#000000}{\left(2+\frac1{4M}\right)}}}}=M\,.$

Consequently the function $\;f(x)=\dfrac{x+1}{x^2+2x-3}\;$ is unbounded on the interval $\,(1,3]\,.$